# Random Forest handle negation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, sklearn-pandas

I'm using Random Forest to apply a sentiment to a string. So basically after cleaning the reviews, which essentially means that stop words (`nltk.corpus -> stopwords` from where I remove words as *no, not, nor, won, wasn, weren*) are removed, as well as non-letter characters, and everything is put is lowercase. The `CountVectorizer` with arguments `(analyzer = "word", tokenizer = None, preprocessor = None, ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words = None, max_features = 5500)` builds the vocabulary and adds it to a `numpy` array. Also I'm using 100 trees.

After splitting the data with `test_size = .1` the classifier is trained, fitted and scored.

`score = forest.score(X_test, y_test)`:
0.882180882181

Confusion matrix, without normalization:

```
[[2256  503]
 [ 519 5269]]
```

Normalized confusion matrix:

```
[[ 0.82  0.18]
 [ 0.09  0.91]]
```

ROC curve showing RandomForest (RF) and RandomForest with LinearRegression(RF + LR):

[image]

[image]

So the problem is that even though the results look very good I get wrong results, for instance:

*"The movie is no good"* -> *negative*

*"The movie is not bad"* -> *negative*

*"The music and imagery aren't good"* -> *positive*

*"The movie didn't make sense"* -> positive

So the above are only some of the problematic cases, but you can get an overall idea what the problem I am facing at the moment is (even using a 3-gram the classifier cannot predict negation properly). I thought that it could be the training set as well, having not enough cases of negation so it can't learn it.

Would you have any suggestion what could be improved or changed so that negation is classified correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question is better suited for the Cross Validated stack exchange, but anyhow.

There are several things that might improve your results:

1. For sentiment analysis it doesn't feel right to remove negation stopwords like 'no', 'not', etc. since they can change totally the positive/negative sentiment of the sentence when constructing the n-grams. In your examples, "not bad", "aren't good", etc. would be transformed into "bad", "good" etc.
2. If you think the negative class is under-represented in your training set, you can balance it by undersampling the positive class.
3. Instead of directly using `predict`, use `predict_proba` and try setting different probability thresholds for separating positive from negative examples.
4. Try a boosting method like AdaBoost or Gradient Boosted Trees, that are better suited to learning exceptions. For example, for learning that a sentence with the word "bad" is generally negative, but if "not bad" is also present, it's positive.